# Prove that $\int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\ln|\frac{x-a}{x+a}|+\zeta$ using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

We know that $\int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|+\zeta$.

> I tried to verify formula using trigonometric substitution and I had some problems.

---

Here is all my steps:

$\int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{sec(\theta)\:d\theta}{tg(\theta)}=\frac{1}{a}\int{csc(\theta)}\:d\theta=-\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}+\frac{a}{x}\right)+\zeta\Rightarrow\theta=\sec^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$.

> How can I continue such that to get $\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|$ ?

Comment: it is easier to use fraction $$\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{1}{2a} (\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{x+a})$$

Comment: Of course, if you're given the candidate antiderivative, it's enough just to differentiate it and see whether you recover the integrand.

Comment: As a general rule, when the denominator can be factorized, partial fraction decomposition makes life easier

Comment: I think your logarithm expression is simply not correct. It is not clear to me how you ended up there, thought... You have two comments above here on how to do this better than doing trigonometric substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$If it matters, the step where you integrate $\csc$ looks awry; should be
$$
\frac{1}{a} \int \csc\theta\, d\theta
  = -\frac{1}{a} \log\left\lvert\csc\theta + \cot\theta\right\rvert + C
  = -\frac{1}{a}\log\left\lvert\frac{x + a}{\sqrt{x^{2} - a^{2}}}\right\rvert + C.
$$
Then factor the radicand as a difference of squares and use properties of logarithms.

Yet another approach (in addition to partial fractions and verifying the formula via differentiation), incidentally, is to use the hyperbolic substitution $x = a\tanh u$, $dx = a\sech^{2} u\, du$ which leads to
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^{2} - a^{2}}
  = \int \frac{a \sech^{2} u\, du}{a^{2} \sech^{2} u}
  = \frac{1}{a} u + C
  = \frac{1}{a} \tanh^{-1} \frac{x}{a} + C
  = \frac{1}{2a} \log \left\lvert \frac{x - a}{x + a} \right\rvert + C.
$$

Comment: Your formula $\frac{1}{2}\tan\theta = \frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{x^{2} - a^{2}}$ is correct, but the calculation of the integral in your preceding comment looks unlikely; perhaps the right-hand side should be $\log\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$...?

Comment: By the half-angle formulas for cos and sin,$$\tan(\theta/2) = \frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos(\theta/2)} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}}.$$Replacing $\cos \theta = 1/\sec\theta$ with $a/x$ gives the desired formula.

Comment: user is neccessary condition at $tanh^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}),|\frac{x}{a}|<1$ ?

Comment: Yes, the domain of $\tanh^{-1}$ is $(-1, 1)$, a.k.a., the image of $\tanh$. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you cannot compute this integral without using partial fractions. If you make the substitution $x= a \sec(\theta)$, your integral "simplifies" to $\int \frac{d \theta}{a \sin \theta}$, from which you can write $\sin \theta = \sqrt {1-\cos^2 \theta}$ and use the substitution $y=\cos x$, which leads to the integral $-\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{dy}{1-y^2}$, which is more or less what you started with!

Thus the only (sensible?) way is to note that $$\int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx = \frac{1}{2a}\left[\int\frac{1}{x-a}dx - \int\frac{1}{x+a}dx\right]$$ and the solution follows immediately as these are elementary integrals.

Comment: Ken Wei , my purpose is to know if work or not with trigonometric substitution... Indeed it is more easy if we decompose in simple fractions, no doubt.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That is why I wrote the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**An other way**

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|+\zeta\right)=\frac{1}{2a}\frac{\frac{(x+a)-(x-a)}{(x+a)^2}}{\frac{x-a}{x+a}}=\frac{1}{(x-a)(x+a)}=\frac{1}{x^2-a^2},$$

and thus,

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|+\zeta.$$

Comment: Surb now can you help with $log$ ? I applied all rules and I obtain something like $\frac{1}{2}(\ln\frac{(x^2+a\sqrt{x^2-a^2})^2}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}})$

Comment: here is all my steps:  $$\ln\frac{x^2+a\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x^2+a\sqrt{x^2-a^2})^2-ln(x^2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}))$$

Comment: what do you mean by "can you help with the log ?" ?

Comment: I want to said if you can help with my method

Comment: May be if could could understand where $\ln\frac{x^2+a\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$ comes from. Notice that the best way to solve those type of integral is (as **darya khostrotash** said) to see that $$\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{x+a}\right).$$

Comment: Surb $\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}+\frac{a}{x})=\ln\frac{x^2+a\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$  was multiply to have at denominator $x^2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ such that we can apply the rule for logarithm: $ln(\frac{a}{b})=ln(a)-ln(b)$

Comment: But why do you want to use $\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+\frac{a}{x}})$ ? I don't see where you want to go... you have to prove $\int \frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|$, so what are you doing with $\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+\frac{a}{x}})$ ? Sorry, but there is no sense to me.

Comment: I don't understand why don't get the same result if I use trigonometric substitution... was just a curiosity and no doubt your method is more easily but it isn't my purpose